# How does Intel TXT prevent spoofing of PCR values?

Tags: trusted-platform-module

I have read some content on trusted execution environment, and I like to ask exactly how it improves hashing. What I read at  [Wikipedia’s “Trusted Execution Technology” article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Execution_Technology) states:

> ...PCRs) which hold various measurements in a shielded location in a manner that prevents spoofing.

**Does this mean one does not have visibility into the result of the hash?**

I’m asking since the process which is described further down on the above mentioned site describes a repeated process of hashing the content with what is in PCRs and storing the result in PCR.

While one does not see the previous results, the state of PCRs is visible to someone who built the prototype or perhaps has access to the platform. I’ld really appreciate some clarification on this.

**How does TPM prevent spoofing, and why was such a measure put in place?**

Was it to protect against someone who would claim a hash belongs to a content, which it really does not? If that‘s correct, then I am definitely missing something.

Comment: The state of the PCR must be visible to a third party, because that value must convince the third party that the system is in a well defined state. "Shielded location" does not mean they are invisible, but it means that they can only be changed in a controlled way.

Comment: Your headline is misleading in 2 aspects. First, you write "Trusted Execution Environment" but you mean "Trusted Execution Technology". Those are two different things. Second, the question has nothing to do with a comparision between a TPM and a TXT.

Comment: @Cryptoasis- I really appreciate your comment. I would gladly yield to your evaluation of the topic. I was contemplating at 3am, when I posted this question, on the appropriate title for this post. I have to say I do have my reasons for the title and sharing them would not benefit the momentum of this topic. I hope I will get more responses on the other portion of my question.

Comment: Spoofing is prevented by the fact that the hash values can only be extended but not replaced. That implies, for instance, that you cannot boot your system with insecure bios settings and then change the pcr hash to the value of a secure bios setting.

Comment: @Cryptoasis- Can we also talk about how close different implementations are to the actual TPM specification? Correct me if I am wrong; I look at TPM as a high level specification and Trusted Execution Environment as one of the implementations of it. I wonder if there is a gap between the two?

Comment: No, you are wrong. The 3 things are different and only partially related. TXT is "trusted execution technology". This is a technology of Intel x86 chips. TEE is "trusted execution environment". That is a GlobalPlatform standard for    developing trusted application.  A well known implementation of a TEE is with The ARM trustzone. TPM is a specification from the Trusted Computing Group. In most cases it is implemented on a seperate smart card controller. TXT provides a secure host environment which supplements the TPM (google "DRTM"). TEE  is not related to TXT or TPM.

Comment: @Cryptostasis - I am not sure if I can still follow up on this topic; I read the TPM book, and feel I like to have a more detailed discussion on how TPM, Trusted Execution Environment, and Trust Zone are similar and different please. Somethings I am not clear on are 1- your latest comment; the part that you say "TEE is "trusted execution environment". That is a GlobalPlatform standard for developing trusted application. A well known implementation of a TEE is with The ARM trustzone.". I do not see how TEE, TPM, and Trust Zone are similar and different. Would you give a high-level explanation?